# UIWebview does not show up into UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tabBar application. In the first tab, I have a navigation bar. In this navigation bar I have a table view. When the user clicks a cell of the table, it goes to another table view, and when the user clicks a cell in that table, it goes to a webview to open a web page.

Basically, it goes fine until opening the webview. In the webview, viewDidLoad is called and seems to work properly. However, webViewDidStartLoad is never called and the web page never shows up.

I am not using IB. I build the UITabBarController in the AppDelegate, where I also assign an instance of my UINavigationController for each tab.

I call the webview from the second UITableViewController as follows:

```
rssWebViewController = [[webViews objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"controller"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:rssWebViewController animated:YES];
```

I have checked that the navigationController is there and it seems just fine.

The viewDidload of my webview is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = self.storyUrl;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[self rssWebView] setDelegate: self];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self rssWebView]];
    [rssWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    self.rssWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; 
    self.rssWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    }
```

The web view controller interface is defined as follows:

```
@interface RSSWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *rssWebView;
    IBOutlet NSString *storyUrl;
    IBOutlet NSString *feedName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *rssWebView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *storyUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *feedName;
@end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found out, I had to initiate my webview with a frame in viewDidLoad:

```
rssWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```